# How to access value of attribute in xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have xml like this:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="2,199">
```

I need to access value of content attribute.
I tried with this

```
"//meta[@itemprop=\"price\"]/@content".
```

Comment: Could you paste you actual xml as-it-is

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a helpful problem description. Please have a look at the [FAQ] and how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

This xpath, escaped as required for your language should retrieve the node you have in the question:

```
//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content
```

If it isn't working I'd suggest double checking how to correctly escape the statement in whatever parent language you are using.